# Using pointers to swap the first character of a string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm kind of new to using pointers in C. So I've been trying to get used to them.
So what I wanted to do was swap the first character of two strings using pointers. This is what I came up with

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_first_char(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char temp = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = temp;
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = "ASTRING";
    char *str2 = "BSTRING";
    swap_first_char(str1,str2);
    printf("str1 = %s, str2 = ‰s\n", str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

So, this is my understanding right now. str1 and str2 hold the address of the first character of "ASTRING" and "BSTRING". 
So when I pass them to the `swap_first_char(char*, char*);` function, now s1 holds the address of the first character of string "ASTRING", and s2 holds the address of the first character of the string "BSTRING". So I could dereference them and swap them to swap the first character of both the strings right?

But I keep getting a segmentation fault on executing this piece of code. If someone can tell me why it is so, I'd be greatful. Thankyou ^_^

Comment: The structure of your code looks fine, but I suspect you're running into the string literals being put in readonly memory (string constants); this can depend on your compiler and architecture.  To see if this is the issue try changing them to `char str1[] = "ABC";` and the like; these allocate for-sure writable arrays.

A reasonable discussion of string constants can be found here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only

Comment: Yep that was indeed the problem. I'll make sure to read that stack exchange thread up. Thanks a lot guys ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding this to an answer where I can use some code: string constants - quoted strings - are often (but not required to be) readonly, and in a sense it's a dirty trick that the compiler allows you to assign one of them to a `char *` (which would allow you to write to it) instead of `const char *` (which would forbid it).

Replacing

```
char *str1 = "ASTRING";
char *str2 = "BSTRING";
```

with

```
char str1[] = "ASTRING";
char str2[] = "BSTRING";
```

does in fact fix the problem (as tested on my x86 system with gcc).  In the latter case, the compiler is allocating the full array of the string (plus the NUL byte), while in the former it's just a pointer to the bytes allocated elsewhere.

Comment: ...and then, when passing the arrays to the function, they decay into pointers, so the function need not be changed.

Comment: Wording of this answer kind of implies first case does not allocate a NULL byte at the end. Also in both case allocations are done by the compiler (who else), its just that in the first case space is allocated (probably) in readonly space whereas in the second case they are allocated in the stack.